# Can Not Store Data From Contact Form To Firebase

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to send the data of my user to firebase using the code given below:

```
var firestore =  firebase.firestore();

var messagesRef = firestore.collection("BookingData");


//listen for submit
document.getElementById('bookingForm').addEventListener('submit',submitForm);

function submitForm(e){
 e.preventDefault();

 //get values
var email = getInputVal('email');
var packageFields = getInputVal('packageFields');
var name = getInputVal('name');
var phone = getInputVal('phone');
var date = getInputVal('date');

}

// function to get form values

 function getInputVal(id) {
return document.getElementById(id).value;
 }

//save messages

function saveMessage(email, packageFields, name, phone, date) {

  messageRef.add({
   email:email,
   packageFields:packageFields,
   name:name,
   phone:phone,
   date:date
   }).then(function(docRef) {
console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
})
 .catch(function(error) {
  console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
});

  }
```

But nothing is happening.

I am not able to send the data to firebase databse.

it also shows a warning called:

> [2020-05-30T03:38:27.083Z]  @firebase/app: 
>       Warning: Firebase is already defined in the global scope. Please make sure
>       Firebase library is only loaded once.

How can I Solve this problem? Please Help/\

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error message saying, you have defined firebase more than once. Check your entire code to make sure it is loaded only one in each scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got The Error I was Not calling The Function. The correct code is:

```
var firestore =  firebase.firestore();

var messagesRef = firestore.collection("BookingData");


//listen for submit
document.getElementById('bookingForm').addEventListener('submit',submitForm);

function submitForm(e){
 e.preventDefault();

 //get values
var email = getInputVal('email');
var packageFields = getInputVal('packageFields');
var name = getInputVal('name');
var phone = getInputVal('phone');
var date = getInputVal('date');

saveMessage(email, packageFields, name, phone, date);
}

// function to get form values

 function getInputVal(id) {
return document.getElementById(id).value;
 }

//save messages

function saveMessage(email, packageFields, name, phone, date) {

  messageRef.add({
   email:email,
   packageFields:packageFields,
   name:name,
   phone:phone,
   date:date
   }).then(function(docRef) {
console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
})
 .catch(function(error) {
  console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
});

}
```